# Is there a pictorial geometric interpretation of the Saint-Venant compatibility equations?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, elasticity, differential-equations, stress-strain

**Is there a pictorial geometric interpretation of the Saint-Venant compatibility equations?**

Other than being a pretty system of equations possessing many symmetries, they don't mean much to me.  The authors, Pei Chi Chou and Nicholas J. Pagano of  [Elasticity: Tensor, Dyadic, and Engineering Approaches](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486669580.html) have promised me these will turn out to be useful, so, perhaps if I keep slogging through the book, I will find the kind of pictorial representation I am seeking.  But, I'm impatient.

Below is a screen-scrape shows the Saint-Venant compatibility equations expressed in my notation.  $\left\{r^a\right\}=\left\{u,v,w\right\}$ is what I call the strain displacement field, which is often written in the right-hand form.

[image: my version]

This is is following the book's notation.  Note that $\gamma_{ab}=2\varepsilon^a{}_b=2r^{a}{}_{,b}$
[image: As in the book]

Comment: What do you mean by pictorial representation?

Comment: In the sense of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler.  See Chapter 8.  In particular section 8.3, and Box 8.3.

Comment: I am not familiar with that reference.